# Wordpress theme error Notice: Undefined index: activated

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I am getting the below error when my page loads in wordpress. How can I prevent this?

```
Notice: Undefined index: activated in /home3/answ/public_html/wp-content/themes/tipztheme/functions.php on line 582

Notice: Undefined index: preview in /home3/answ/public_html/wp-content/themes/tipztheme/functions.php on line 582
```

Here is the code on line 508 that is causing the error.  Line 508 is the  `if ( $_GET['activated'] == 'true'  || $_GET['preview'] == 1 )`  your help is much appreciated!

```
 Plugin Name: DDThemes - Logo Options
 Plugin URI: http://www.designdisease.com/
 */

 //ADD OPTION PAGE
 add_action('admin_menu', 'ddthemes_admin');

 //UPON ACTIVATION OR PREVIEWED
 if ( $_GET['activated'] == 'true'  || $_GET['preview'] == 1 )
 {
ddthemes_setup();
 }

 function ddthemes_admin() 
 {
    /* PROCESS OPTION SAVING HERE */
if ( 'save' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) 
{
    if ( $_REQUEST['savetype'] == 'header' )
    {
        update_option( 'ddthemes_header', $_REQUEST['ddthemes_header']);
    }

}

/* SHOW THEME CUSTOMIZE PAGE HERE */
add_theme_page(__('Logo Options'), __('Logo Options'), 'edit_themes', basename(__FILE__), 'ddthemes_headeropt_page');}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error appears because of your PHP error reporting settings. It appears when your variable is not properly set. To be honest this is not exactly a really big deal and that is good;=) To solve it you have couple of options: option one is to SET your variable before being used and add some dummy value to it for example:

```
  if (!isset($_REQUEST['savetype']))
  {
  //If not set add some dummy value
  $_REQUEST['savetype'] = "undefine";
  } 

  if ( $_REQUEST['savetype'] == 'header' )
  {
    update_option( 'ddthemes_header', $_REQUEST['ddthemes_header']);
  }
```

Another solution is to modify (suppress error reporting) in your **php.ini** and insert this line:

```
<?php error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); ?>
```

And yet another solution is also to supress error reporting but this time in your **wp-config.php** instead this:`define('WP_DEBUG', true);` add `define('WP_DEBUG', false);`

Funny thing is I had the same problem today and first option worked for me:) Hope it helps... Cheers!